# Laurent series for $\exp(-x)$ centered at infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to expand $\exp(-x)$ in a series centered at infinity, i.e. , 
$\exp(-x)=\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}b_n (x-\infty)^n$

Obviously, this does not make sense, so what I did is:

We define $z=1/x$ such that now the expansion is centered at zero, i.e.,
$\exp(-1/z)=\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n z^n$

where

$a_n=\frac{1}{2 \pi \imath }\oint_C dz \frac{e^{-1/z}}{z^{n+1}}$,

and the contour C is taken in any way  such that contains the origin.

Then, for $n\leq 1$, the function integrating is analytic in all complex space. Thus, the integral is zero. However, for all other $n$ I used the residue theorem and obtained

$a_n=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dz^n}(\exp(-1/z) ) $
$ = \lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{n!} e^{-1/z}P_{2n}(\frac{1}{z}) $

here $P_{2n}(x)$ is a polinomial of order $2n$. But this result says that for all $n$ finite $a_n=0$, but I'm not sure if this is correct, and if it is then how would the Laurent expansion would be?

So, how could I express $\exp(-x)$ in a series centered at infinity, so that the first term of the series is the heaviest?

This is for an approximation I'm doing where the function I'm approximating is $exp(-N\sigma)$ ($N$ being number of particles, which is a big number), and I want to be able to make first order approx, 2nd order approx, and so.

Thanx!

Comment: "Laurent series centered at $\infty$" is not a standard concept.  Can you site a reference for it?

Comment: $e^{-1/z}$ is not analytic at  origin and has a Laurent series in the form: $1-z^{-1}+z^{-2}/2!-z^{-3}/3!+...$

Comment: @Albert, if a complex variable function $f(z)$ (where $z=x+\imath y$) is analytic in some domain, then, the real part of the function and the imaginary part of the function satisfies Laplace Eq., i.e, writing the function as $f(z)=u(x,y)+\imath v(x,y)$, then

$\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=0$

The same for $v(x,y)$.

In my function, $u(x,y)=\exp(-\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})\cos(y/(x^2+y^2))$ and $v(x,y)=-\exp(-\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})\sin(y/(x^2+y^2))$, which does satisfy Laplace Eq. for all $x$ and $y$. Hence, $\exp(-1/z)$ is analytic in all complex space

Comment: @GEdgar, what I use for this sort of things is a book I used in the career, and is a cuban book. So I guess it is not online, still, the author is Jose Marin. However, the bibliography of this book are books of mathematical analysis and analytic functions and some of the authors are Apostol, Lavrientriev, Morse and Feshbach (Methods of theoretical physics), Smirnov, Tokhonov. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have written, the functions $u$ and $v$ are not defined at zero and hence they are not differentiable at origin.  Well, only thing that we can say is that $\exp({-1/z})$ is analytic at any point $z_{0}\in C-\{0\}$ and at  $z_{0}=0$ the function has an essential isolated singularity. For more details see "Comlex Variables and Applications by Brown and Churchill", Chapters 2 and  5 (sec 62).

Comment: I see what you mean, and, yes, you're right, the function has an essential singularity. Thanks a lot!